# Changing constraint colors in pymunk/pygame

Tags: pygame, chipmunk, pymunk

I am working on a project using pymunk and pygame. I am using PivotJoint constraints to attach my bodies together. I would like to make the joints invisible if possible - is there any way to do this? Right now the joints appear purple in pygame and I don't seem to be able to change their color.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can disable drawing of constraints by setting the flags property on the SpaceDebugDrawOptions object to only include shapes, or if you prefer include both shapes and collisions: http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.html#pymunk.SpaceDebugDrawOptions.flags

in this way to draw only shapes

```
options = pymunk.pygame_util.DrawOptions(screen)
options.flags = pymunk.SpaceDebugDrawOptions.DRAW_SHAPES
```

or like this to draw both shapes and collisions

```
options = pymunk.pygame_util.DrawOptions(screen)
options.flags = pymunk.SpaceDebugDrawOptions.DRAW_SHAPES | pymunk.SpaceDebugDrawOptions.DRAW_COLLISION_POINTS
```